# Place for shopping questions

Tags: discussion

A few weeks ago, maybe a 1 1/2 month, I saw a post somewhere that linked to a new website that was for IT Shopping questions - basically they said here is now a place in the style of stackoverflow where you can put shopping questions...

1) I don't recall the site name/URL. Anyone has it somewhere?

2) We could refer to it maybe to people who ask shopping questions... if that site is any good.

Comment: Only *software* shopping questions, that still leaves a place for hardware.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're thinking of http://techshoppingand.info/ - it... doesn't seem very active.

Comment: That's what I was trying to find but I'm glad we have Software Recommendations now there as that seems better.

Comment: I agree; I like to keep in in-ecosystem as much as possible.

Comment: I'm trying to drive traffic to it, but all I seem to get is a huge spam problem.  I'd like to get a stack for it, like Software Recommendations, but the SE team seem pretty hard on the no shopping thing.

Answer (score 8):

[Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) has recently entered public beta.

Comment: If ever there was a website where I wanted to ask "What is the best *nix command line file editor" this is it!

Comment: That's nice! At least there is a correct place for these questions. Let's see how this site goes - if the questions are tagged well, it should work.

Comment: Once it is out of beta we need it in the migration list.